# Selecting leaflet markers

Tags: javascript, html, json, leaflet, geojson

I have data coming from a Json file and I created a layer based on this Json file using markerClusterGroup. I am hitting the wall trying to do this:

1 - Select some markers based on some Json's feature ("temperatura", "salinidade","corrente", "profundidade" e "geofisico") in xbt.json and using a select list in the HTML:

```
<select name="sometext" >
  <option value="temperatura">temperatura</option>
  <option value="salinidade">salinidade</option>
  <option value="corrente">corrente</option>
  <option value="profundidade">profundidade</option>
  <option value="geofisico">geofisico</option>
</select>
```

Based on the way I am adding the json to the map using popups and makercluster (see code below), How can I select (show on map) only the markers related to specific json features: temperatura, salinidade and so on?

```
var xbt = getJson('geojson/xbt.json');
    var markers_xbt = L.markerClusterGroup();
    var estacoes_xbt = L.geoJson(xbt, { 
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) //functionality on click on feature
                {
                layer.bindPopup("Navio: "+feature.properties.navio+"<br>"+"Comissao: "+feature.properties.comissao+"<br>"+ "Bandeira do Navio:"+feature.properties.naviobandeira+"<br>"+"Equipamento: "+feature.properties.equipamento+"<br>"+ "Inicio da Comissao:"+feature.properties.iniciocomissao+"<br>"+"Fim da Comissao : "+feature.properties.fimcomissao+"<br>"+"Data de Lancamento: "+ feature.properties.estacaodata+"<br>"+"Hora de Lancamento: " +feature.properties.estacaohora+"<br>"+"Quadrado de Marsden: "+feature.properties.quadrado+"<br>"+"Subquadrado de Marsden: "+feature.properties.subquadrado ); //just to show something in the popup. could be part of the geojson as well!
                }

            });
        markers_xbt.addLayer(estacoes_xbt); // add it to the cluster group
        map.addLayer(markers_xbt);      // add it to the map
        map.fitBounds(markers_xbt.getBounds()); //set view on the cluster extend
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, have a select element with ID 'my-select', get a reference and attach an eventhandler:

```
var select = L.DomUtil.get('my-select');

L.DomEvent.addListener(select, 'change', changeHandler);
```

Now in the `changeHandler` method, iterate over all the layers in your cluster and move all the layers from your cluster which don't correspond with the select value to a temporary array:

```
// Array for temporarily storing layers which are out of cluster
var layers = [];

function changeHandler (e) {
    // Any layers stored?
    if (layers.length > 0) {
        // Iterate layers
        layers.forEach(function (layer) {
            // Return to the cluster
            cluster.addLayer(layer);
        });
    }
    // Iterate cluster
    cluster.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        // Compare layer feature value with select value
        if (e.target.value !== layer.feature.properties.value) {
            // No match, move to layers
            layers.push(layer);
            // Remove from cluster
            cluster.removeLayer(layer);
        }
    });
}
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LZIEIE?p=preview

Comment: Dear iH8 Thank you for your great job. Now take a look at my site http://brasilgeotube.tk/ please, How could I select a specific GPS station using a json feature in the gps json file. For instance, among all the layers on the map, select only the GPS station "VICO". Thank you very much. All the overlayers will hind and the leaf "VICO" will display.