# Filter Json Features by HTML SELECT object

Tags: javascript, html, json, leaflet, geojson

I have the following websites [Brazil1](http://brasilgeotube.herobo.com/) and [Brazil2](http://brasilgeotube.tk)

I uploaded some GPS stations (Json point features) and I am in need to select an specific GPS station (based on the station name "Estação RBMC) using a HTML select Object:

```
<select name="sometext" >
  <option value="MGRP">mgrp</option>
  <option value="MGV1">mgv1</option>
  <option value="VICO">vico</option>
  <option value="MGBH">mgbh</option>
  </select>
```

My first attempt was [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996430/selecting-leaflet-markers), but I did not understand much.

Could someone give a tip on that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to specify in the `select` element is the `id`, because that is what you will use to add event listeners. Something like this:

```
<select id="sta_select">
  <option>(select station)</option>
  <option value="MGRP">mgrp</option>
  <option value="MGV1">mgv1</option>
  <option value="VICO">vico</option>
  <option value="MGBH">mgbh</option>
</select>
```

You can then add event listeners based on that `id`:

```
var sta_select = L.DomUtil.get("sta_select");
L.DomEvent.addListener(sta_select, 'click', function (e) {
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
});
L.DomEvent.addListener(sta_select, 'change', changeHandler);
```

The `click` listener with the `stopPropagation` method is to prevent clicks on the selector from propagating through to the map if they overlap with the map pane, which could (depending on your settings) immediately unselect the layer you are trying to highlight. The `change` listener will run a handler function, which you can set to do anything you want. Here, I've set it to open the popup for a marker when its corresponding `option` is selected (based on a match between the `value` attribute in the option element and the `SG_RBMC` property in the geoJson layer):

```
function changeHandler(e) {
    for (i in estacoes_rbmc._layers) {
        if (estacoes_rbmc._layers[i].feature.properties.SG_RBMC === e.target.value) {
            estacoes_rbmc._layers[i].openPopup();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle that shows it at work:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/80qcstLf/

and also a somewhat fancier version that puts the select element on the map inside a Leaflet control and automatically populates the option attributes:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/avn0ph1p/

Comment: could you give a tip on how to change the leaflet.css so the leaflet control for selector gets out of the area covered by the basemap? The selector position is set on the topright of the map, but I want it on the topright of my html and out of the map.